# Optimized query to find avg in MySQL with inner join

Tags: mysql, average, sqlperformance

Currently I am running a query to find average with joining one more table.
Results are as expected but it does not perform very well, taking a lot of time to execute. So need a help to find the better query. Current query is:

```
SELECT AVG(t2.a),
       AVG(t2.b),
       AVG(t2.c),
       t1.column1,
       t1.column2
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.column = t2.column
GROUP BY t1.column1, t2.column2
```

Comment: Do you have to execute an identical average three times?

Comment: no there are 3 different columns.

Answer (score 0):

In the future when asking questions related to performance please always include an [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html) output. You basically just write "EXPLAIN SELECT ....;" and it'll show you the execution plan of that query which includes detailed information which may hint towards possible optimizations.

Two things:

JOINs on unindexed columns may be very slow.

GROUP BY statements are generally slow kind of queries as they require sorting, especially when grouping multiple columns. GROUP BY can do index scans but this requires that there's tuple indexes on the involved columns which in your case since you're selecting columns from different tables probably doesn't work.

How many rows do you have? If you're grouping hundreds of million of rows you can easily expect query times that are in the range of **hours** (and I'm dead serious about hours). Grouping is just a horrifically expensive operation. Especially because you have memory limits which means the sorting takes place on-disk which induces an additional slowdown due to disk i/o which is just soo much slower than memory.

Comment: currently EXPLAIN is giving below result for the query:

Comment: *************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: mid
   partitions: NULL
         type: ALL
possible_keys: PRIMARY,UIDX_mac_ifid
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 8114
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using temporary; Using filesort

Comment: *************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: m
   partitions: NULL
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,UIDX_mac,IDX_mac_time
          key: UIDX_mac
      key_len: 25
          ref: summit_lab.mid.mac_address
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index condition

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible answers.

- The query is wrong -- Because the `JOIN` occurs before the `AVERAGE`, hence the average is of too many rows.
- The query is right -- in which case, there is a lot of work to do, so it takes time.  I have to believe that this is the case, since you `GROUP BY` columns from both tables.

Please provide real column names; it could help our understanding of the query.

But assuming the first case, let's fix the math *and* speed it up.

1. Computer the averages in a "derived" table.
2. Do the `JOIN`.

I won't attempt to write the code until I have some assurance that the case is worth pursuing.